# Decompose binary into decimal units, tens and hundreds

Tags: functions, binary, binary-operations

I have a 9 bit binary sequence (from 0 0000 0000 to 1 1111 1111) and I'd like to decompose into decimal units, tens and hundreds.

**Consider the following:**

*0 0111 1011 ==> 123*

I'd like to decompose it into:

```
0001 => 1  
0010 => 2  
0011 => 3
```

Having 3 different functions (one for units one for tens and one for hundreds) is preferable

Would it be possible to get from **any** 9 bit sequence from 3 functions a decomposition?
One function would do units, one would do tens and another would handle hundreds.

It would be even better using logic only (AND, NAND, NOT, OR, XOR, NOR and NXOR)

Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: hint: any binary representation can be (unnumerically) transformed into quarternary,octal and hexa, what is the closest to decimal ?thereafter, you can use as little calculations as required to transform to base 10

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing [natural binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) on the numbers $0$ to $511$.  If your number is $N$, then $H=\lfloor N/100 \rfloor, T=\lfloor (N-100H)/10 \rfloor, U=N-100H-10T$ gives the result you seek with $H$ the hundreds, $T$ the tens, $U$ the units.  Then convert $H,T,U$ to binary, probably using a table as there are only ten choices.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i was looking for something like the [Double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble)  
Any idea how to do this using no loops and one function per BCD (binary-coded decimal)

Comment: If you knew of that (I didn't), you should say so.  Your cases are certainly few enough that a lookup table would be reasonable.  I believe there are tools out there that can take a table and convert them to logic, but I don't know where they are.

Comment: Just discovered thanks to you ;) And a lookup table is possible, but 521 values is a lot, I'm trying to do everything by hand ;)